# Autocomplete textfield in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, autocomplete, textfield

I am currently working on a JavaFX project with Mongo DB as backend. I want to add a textfield which autocompletes typed text with suggestions. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at AutoComplete TextFields from [ControlFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#textfields). A guide for the same can be found [here](http://kaykovus.blogspot.in/2015/01/how-to-use-controlsfx-autocomplete.html).

Comment: Thank you @ItachiUchiha how to use document listener in javafx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX TextField Auto-suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861056/javafx-textfield-auto-suggestions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ControlsFX 8.0.5 jar in program

```
 TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textfield id,"text to suggest");
```