# JavaFX TextField Auto-suggestions

Tags: javafx, autocomplete, lucene, textfield, autosuggest

I want to make this TextField have suggestions feature just like in Lucene. I've searched all the web and I just find it for ComboBox.

```
TextField instNameTxtFld = instNameTxtFld();

private TextField instNameTxtFld() {
    TextField txtFld = new TextField();
    txtFld.setPrefSize(600, 75);
    return txtFld;
}
```

The reason that I can't use the method for ComboBox is because I can't input the value to database below if I use ComboBox.

```
private void goNext() {

    if (nameTxtFld.getText() == null || nameTxtFld.getText().trim().isEmpty()
            || instNameTxtFld.getText()== null || instNameTxtFld.getText().trim().isEmpty()
            || addTxtArea.getText() == null || addTxtArea.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        alertDialog.showAndWait();
    } else {
        String satu = idNumTxtFld.getText();
        String dua = nameTxtFld.getText();
        String tiga = addTxtArea.getText();
        String empat = instNameTxtFld.getText();
        int delapan = idType.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        String sembilan = timeStamp.getText();
        try {
            KonekDB.createConnection();
            Statement st = KonekDB.conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO privateguest"
                    + "(idNumber, name, address, institution, idType, startTime) "
                    + "VALUES "
                    + "('" + satu + "','" + dua + "','" + tiga + "','" + empat + "','" + delapan + "','" + sembilan + "')";

            System.out.println(sql);
            st.executeUpdate(sql);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            System.out.println(satu + " " + dua + " " + tiga + " " + empat + " " + delapan + " " + sembilan);
            System.out.println("SQL Exception (next)");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Frame3Private frame3 = new Frame3Private(english);
        this.getScene().setRoot(frame3);
    }

}
```

Please help me to make the most simple code for doing TextField suggestions/ auto-complete.

Comment: Did you consider using `AutoComplete` from [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/)?

Answer (score 22):

Here is my solution based on [This](https://gist.github.com/floralvikings/10290131).

```
public class AutocompletionlTextField extends TextFieldWithLengthLimit {
    //Local variables
    //entries to autocomplete
    private final SortedSet<String> entries;      
    //popup GUI
    private ContextMenu entriesPopup;


    public AutocompletionlTextField() {
        super();
        this.entries = new TreeSet<>();
        this.entriesPopup = new ContextMenu();

        setListner();
    }  


    /**
     * wrapper for default constructor with setting of "TextFieldWithLengthLimit" LengthLimit
     * 
     * @param lengthLimit 
     */
    public AutocompletionlTextField(int lengthLimit) {        
        this();
        super.setLengthLimit(lengthLimit);                
    }


    /**
     * "Suggestion" specific listners
     */
    private void setListner() {     
        //Add "suggestions" by changing text
        textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            String enteredText = getText();
            //always hide suggestion if nothing has been entered (only "spacebars" are dissalowed in TextFieldWithLengthLimit)
            if (enteredText == null || enteredText.isEmpty()) {
                entriesPopup.hide();
            } else {
                //filter all possible suggestions depends on "Text", case insensitive
                List<String> filteredEntries = entries.stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.toLowerCase().contains(enteredText.toLowerCase()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                //some suggestions are found
                if (!filteredEntries.isEmpty()) {
                    //build popup - list of "CustomMenuItem"
                    populatePopup(filteredEntries, enteredText);
                    if (!entriesPopup.isShowing()) { //optional
                        entriesPopup.show(AutocompletionlTextField.this, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0); //position of popup
                    }
                //no suggestions -> hide
                } else {
                    entriesPopup.hide();
                }
            }
        });

        //Hide always by focus-in (optional) and out
        focusedProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            entriesPopup.hide();
        });
    }             


    /**
    * Populate the entry set with the given search results. Display is limited to 10 entries, for performance.
    * 
    * @param searchResult The set of matching strings.
    */
    private void populatePopup(List<String> searchResult, String searchReauest) {
        //List of "suggestions"
        List<CustomMenuItem> menuItems = new LinkedList<>();
        //List size - 10 or founded suggestions count
        int maxEntries = 10;
        int count = Math.min(searchResult.size(), maxEntries);
        //Build list as set of labels
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          final String result = searchResult.get(i);
          //label with graphic (text flow) to highlight founded subtext in suggestions
          Label entryLabel = new Label();
          entryLabel.setGraphic(Styles.buildTextFlow(result, searchReauest));  
          entryLabel.setPrefHeight(10);  //don't sure why it's changed with "graphic"
          CustomMenuItem item = new CustomMenuItem(entryLabel, true);
          menuItems.add(item);

          //if any suggestion is select set it into text and close popup
          item.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
              setText(result);
              positionCaret(result.length());
              entriesPopup.hide();
          });
        }

        //"Refresh" context menu
        entriesPopup.getItems().clear();
        entriesPopup.getItems().addAll(menuItems);
    }


    /**
    * Get the existing set of autocomplete entries.
    * 
    * @return The existing autocomplete entries.
    */
    public SortedSet<String> getEntries() { return entries; }
}
```

You must extends from "TextField" instead of "TextFieldWithLengthLimit" and delete constructor with "Length limit".

I use static methods to work with Styles. It's used here to "highlight" entered text inside suggestion results. Here is the code of methos from this class:

```
/**
 * Build TextFlow with selected text. Return "case" dependent.
 * 
 * @param text - string with text
 * @param filter - string to select in text
 * @return - TextFlow
 */
public static TextFlow buildTextFlow(String text, String filter) {        
    int filterIndex = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase());
    Text textBefore = new Text(text.substring(0, filterIndex));
    Text textAfter = new Text(text.substring(filterIndex + filter.length()));
    Text textFilter = new Text(text.substring(filterIndex,  filterIndex + filter.length())); //instead of "filter" to keep all "case sensitive"
    textFilter.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
    textFilter.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));  
    return new TextFlow(textBefore, textFilter, textAfter);
}
```

You may add this "AutocompletionlTextField" in FXML (dont forget about "imports") or inside constructor. To set "suggestions" list on use "entries" getter:

```
AutocompletionlTextField field = new AutocompletionlTextField();
field.getEntries().addAll(YOUR_ARRAY_OF_STRINGS);
```

It seems like that in my application:
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where is TextFieldWithLengthLimit located ?

Comment: It was my own comonent - you heed to use TextField instead. As in my comment wrotten: "You must extends from "TextField" instead of "TextFieldWithLengthLimit" and delete constructor with "Length limit"".

Comment: ok thanks, try to post working code next time and post the TextFieldWithLengthLimit code also...

Comment: I want to trigger function on selecting value from autocompletiontextfield. How we can achieve this?

Comment: Sorry I don't have this code any more and don't work with JavaFX currently, so I can't say unfourtenately:(

Comment: @SatishPahuja My answer builds upon this answer and allows you to use the selected object. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56173327/9278333

Comment: Thank you for this code. It is really nice and useful. I did some changes and added the TextField from FXML view file to AutocompletionlTextField.
just few adits at AutocompletionlTextField class.  

        `AutocompletionlTextField field = new AutocompletionlTextField(searchTF);
        field.getEntries().addAll(getAllSearchStrArray());`

Answer (score 13):

You can use ControlsFX --> [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx)

Solution:

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textfield,"text to suggest", "another text to suggest");
```

Comment: Quick solution. But it's really slow to popup, i can type the entire word before the popup shows up.

Comment: looking at the code for autocomplete of controlsfx you can tweak the the default delay of 350ms which is large....

Answer (score 8):

This example https://gist.github.com/floralvikings/10290131 only allowed Strings.

I edited it to allow any object and just use that object's `toString` method. This allows you to use the object selected to do other things rather than just populate the TextField. Also fixed a bug where an exception would occur if you are deleting a `String` in the `TextField` that is not a part of the entries.

Example usage:

```
SortedSet<Address> entries = new TreeSet<>((Address o1, Address o2) -> o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString()));

entries.add(new Address("50", "Main Street", "Oakville", "Ontario", "T6P4K9"));
entries.add(new Address("3", "Fuller Road", "Toronto", "Ontario", "B6S4T9"));

AutoCompleteTextField<Address> text = new AutoCompleteTextField(entries);

text.getEntryMenu().setOnAction(e ->
{
    ((MenuItem) e.getTarget()).addEventHandler(Event.ANY, event ->
    {
         if (text.getLastSelectedObject() != null)
         {
            text.setText(text.getLastSelectedObject().toString());
            System.out.println(text.getLastSelectedObject().getProvince());
         }
    });
});
```

[image]

**AutoCompleteTextField.java**

```
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;

/**
 * This class is a TextField which implements an "autocomplete" functionality,
 * based on a supplied list of entries.<p>
 *
 * If the entered text matches a part of any of the supplied entries these are
 * going to be displayed in a popup. Further the matching part of the entry is
 * going to be displayed in a special style, defined by
 * {@link #textOccurenceStyle textOccurenceStyle}. The maximum number of
 * displayed entries in the popup is defined by
 * {@link #maxEntries maxEntries}.<br>
 * By default the pattern matching is not case-sensitive. This behaviour is
 * defined by the {@link #caseSensitive caseSensitive}
 * .<p>
 *
 * The AutoCompleteTextField also has a List of
 * {@link #filteredEntries filteredEntries} that is equal to the search results
 * if search results are not empty, or {@link #filteredEntries filteredEntries}
 * is equal to {@link #entries entries} otherwise. If
 * {@link #popupHidden popupHidden} is set to true no popup is going to be
 * shown. This list can be used to bind all entries to another node (a ListView
 * for example) in the following way:
 * <pre>
 * <code>
 * AutoCompleteTextField auto = new AutoCompleteTextField(entries);
 * auto.setPopupHidden(true);
 * SimpleListProperty filteredEntries = new SimpleListProperty(auto.getFilteredEntries());
 * listView.itemsProperty().bind(filteredEntries);
 * </code>
 * </pre>
 *
 * @author Caleb Brinkman
 * @author Fabian Ochmann
 * @param <S>
 */
public class AutoCompleteTextField<S> extends TextField
{

    private final ObjectProperty<S> lastSelectedItem = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    /**
     * The existing autocomplete entries.
     */
    private final SortedSet<S> entries;

    /**
     * The set of filtered entries:<br>
     * Equal to the search results if search results are not empty, equal to
     * {@link #entries entries} otherwise.
     */
    private ObservableList<S> filteredEntries
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * The popup used to select an entry.
     */
    private ContextMenu entriesPopup;

    /**
     * Indicates whether the search is case sensitive or not. <br>
     * Default: false
     */
    private boolean caseSensitive = false;

    /**
     * Indicates whether the Popup should be hidden or displayed. Use this if
     * you want to filter an existing list/set (for example values of a
     * {@link javafx.scene.control.ListView ListView}). Do this by binding
     * {@link #getFilteredEntries() getFilteredEntries()} to the list/set.
     */
    private boolean popupHidden = false;

    /**
     * The CSS style that should be applied on the parts in the popup that match
     * the entered text. <br>
     * Default: "-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-fill: red;"
     * <p>
     * Note: This style is going to be applied on an
     * {@link javafx.scene.text.Text Text} instance. See the <i>JavaFX CSS
     * Reference Guide</i> for available CSS Propeties.
     */
    private String textOccurenceStyle = "-fx-font-weight: bold; "
            + "-fx-fill: red;";

    /**
     * The maximum Number of entries displayed in the popup.<br>
     * Default: 10
     */
    private int maxEntries = 10;

    /**
     * Construct a new AutoCompleteTextField.
     *
     * @param entrySet
     */
    public AutoCompleteTextField(SortedSet<S> entrySet)
    {
        super();
        this.entries = (entrySet == null ? new TreeSet<>() : entrySet);
        this.filteredEntries.addAll(entries);

        entriesPopup = new ContextMenu();

        textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String s2) ->
        {

            if (getText() == null || getText().length() == 0)
            {
                filteredEntries.clear();
                filteredEntries.addAll(entries);
                entriesPopup.hide();
            } else
            {
                LinkedList<S> searchResult = new LinkedList<>();
                //Check if the entered Text is part of some entry
                String text1 = getText();
                Pattern pattern;
                if (isCaseSensitive())
                {
                    pattern = Pattern.compile(".*" + text1 + ".*");
                } else
                {
                    pattern = Pattern.compile(".*" + text1 + ".*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                }
                for (S entry : entries)
                {
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(entry.toString());
                    if (matcher.matches())
                    {
                        searchResult.add(entry);
                    }
                }
                if (!entries.isEmpty())
                {
                    filteredEntries.clear();
                    filteredEntries.addAll(searchResult);
                    //Only show popup if not in filter mode
                    if (!isPopupHidden())
                    {
                        populatePopup(searchResult, text1);
                        if (!entriesPopup.isShowing())
                        {
                            entriesPopup.show(AutoCompleteTextField.this, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                        }
                    }
                } else
                {
                    entriesPopup.hide();
                }
            }
        });

        focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean, Boolean aBoolean2) ->
        {
            entriesPopup.hide();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Get the existing set of autocomplete entries.
     *
     * @return The existing autocomplete entries.
     */
    public SortedSet<S> getEntries()
    {
        return entries;
    }

    /**
     * Populate the entry set with the given search results. Display is limited
     * to 10 entries, for performance.
     *
     * @param searchResult The set of matching strings.
     */
    private void populatePopup(List<S> searchResult, String text)
    {
        List<CustomMenuItem> menuItems = new LinkedList<>();
        int count = Math.min(searchResult.size(), getMaxEntries());
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            final String result = searchResult.get(i).toString();
            final S itemObject = searchResult.get(i);
            int occurence;

            if (isCaseSensitive())
            {
                occurence = result.indexOf(text);
            } else
            {
                occurence = result.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase());
            }
            if (occurence < 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            //Part before occurence (might be empty)
            Text pre = new Text(result.substring(0, occurence));
            //Part of (first) occurence
            Text in = new Text(result.substring(occurence, occurence + text.length()));
            in.setStyle(getTextOccurenceStyle());
            //Part after occurence
            Text post = new Text(result.substring(occurence + text.length(), result.length()));

            TextFlow entryFlow = new TextFlow(pre, in, post);

            CustomMenuItem item = new CustomMenuItem(entryFlow, true);
            item.setOnAction((ActionEvent actionEvent) ->
            {
                lastSelectedItem.set(itemObject);
                entriesPopup.hide();
            });
            menuItems.add(item);
        }
        entriesPopup.getItems().clear();
        entriesPopup.getItems().addAll(menuItems);

    }

    public S getLastSelectedObject()
    {
        return lastSelectedItem.get();
    }

    public ContextMenu getEntryMenu()
    {
        return entriesPopup;
    }

    public boolean isCaseSensitive()
    {
        return caseSensitive;
    }

    public String getTextOccurenceStyle()
    {
        return textOccurenceStyle;
    }

    public void setCaseSensitive(boolean caseSensitive)
    {
        this.caseSensitive = caseSensitive;
    }

    public void setTextOccurenceStyle(String textOccurenceStyle)
    {
        this.textOccurenceStyle = textOccurenceStyle;
    }

    public boolean isPopupHidden()
    {
        return popupHidden;
    }

    public void setPopupHidden(boolean popupHidden)
    {
        this.popupHidden = popupHidden;
    }

    public ObservableList<S> getFilteredEntries()
    {
        return filteredEntries;
    }

    public int getMaxEntries()
    {
        return maxEntries;
    }

    public void setMaxEntries(int maxEntries)
    {
        this.maxEntries = maxEntries;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is another solution with [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/%22JFoenix%22). Since February 2018 they added autocompletion class. This is implementation of it.

```
// when initializing the window or in some other method
void initialize() {
    JFXAutoCompletePopup<String> autoCompletePopup = new JFXAutoCompletePopup<>();
    autoCompletePopup.getSuggestions().addAll("option1", "option2", "...");

    autoCompletePopup.setSelectionHandler(event -> {
        textField.setText(event.getObject());

        // you can do other actions here when text completed
    });

    // filtering options
    textField.textProperty().addListener(observable -> {
        autoCompletePopup.filter(string -> string.toLowerCase().contains(textField.getText().toLowerCase()));
        if (autoCompletePopup.getFilteredSuggestions().isEmpty() || textField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            autoCompletePopup.hide();
            // if you remove textField.getText.isEmpty() when text field is empty it suggests all options
            // so you can choose
        } else {
            autoCompletePopup.show(textField);
        }
    });
}
```

This is a bit new approach and worked fine with me. Hope it will help and thanks to JFoenix developers.

Comment: Have you been able to do CSS styling of the drop down list which shows when we use this Auto Complete feature? Either with JFoenix or ControlsFx ?

Comment: This is the best approach.  Thank you.

Comment: @iCoder

You can style it using .autocomplete-list  and  .autocomplete-pane style class(es).:


.autocomplete-list {

 -fx-padding: 5;
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto";
 -fx-font-size: 16;
    -fx-font-smoothing-type: gray;
}

.autocomplete-pane {

 -fx-padding: 5;
 -fx-background-color: lightskyblue;
}

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution - a complete method only with a ComboBox parameter:

```
 /**
 * My own autocomplete combobox
 *
 * @param categoryComboBox
 */
public static void bindAutoCompleteToComboBox(ComboBox<String> categoryComboBox) {

    /**
     * backup the original list
     */
    List<String> categoryComboBoxItemsList = new ArrayList<String>(categoryComboBox.getItems());

    /**
     * if mouse pressed: select all of the text field
     */
    categoryComboBox.getEditor().setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (categoryComboBox.getEditor().isFocused() && !categoryComboBox.getEditor().getText().isEmpty()) {
                        categoryComboBox.getEditor().selectAll();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    /**
     * events on text input
     */
    categoryComboBox.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        private List<String> reducedList = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getCode().isLetterKey() || event.getCode().isDigitKey() || event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)) {

                /**
                 * Open comboBox if letter, number or backspace
                 */
                categoryComboBox.show();

                String temp = categoryComboBox.getEditor().getText();
                reducedList = new ArrayList<String>();

                /**
                 * If backspace pressed, selection refers to the basic list again
                 */
                if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)) {
                    categoryComboBox.getItems().clear();
                    categoryComboBox.getItems().addAll(categoryComboBoxItemsList);

                    // java fx workaround to restore the default list height of 10
                    categoryComboBox.hide();
                    categoryComboBox.setVisibleRowCount(10);
                    categoryComboBox.show();
                }

                /**
                 * loop through all entrys and look whether input contains this text.
                 *
                 * after that, entry will be added to the reduced list
                 */
                for (String element : categoryComboBox.getItems()) {
                    if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(element, temp)) {
                        reducedList.add(element);
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * all elements are cleared, the reduced list will be added. First element is selected
                 */
                categoryComboBox.getItems().clear();
                categoryComboBox.getItems().addAll(reducedList);
                categoryComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
                categoryComboBox.getEditor().setText(temp);

            } else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {

                /**
                 * if enter, the element which is selected will be applied to the text field and the dropdown will be closed
                 */
                if (categoryComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
                    categoryComboBox.getEditor().setText(categoryComboBox.getItems().get((categoryComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex())));
                } else {
                    categoryComboBox.getEditor().setText(categoryComboBox.getItems().get(0));
                }

            } else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DOWN)) {

                /**
                 * arrow down shows the dropdown
                 */
                categoryComboBox.show();
            }

            /**
             * Tab marks everything (when tabbing into the field
             */
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.TAB)) {

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (categoryComboBox.getEditor().isFocused() && !categoryComboBox.getEditor().getText().isEmpty()) {
                            categoryComboBox.getEditor().selectAll();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                /**
                 * all entries except for tab put the caret on the last character
                 */
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        categoryComboBox.getEditor().positionCaret(categoryComboBox.getEditor().getText().length());
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * focus lost
     */
    categoryComboBox.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        /**
         * if focus lost: refill the category combo box with the original items
         */
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

            if (oldValue) {

                /**
                 * saves whether textfield was empty before reset the comboBox
                 */
                boolean emptyTextField = categoryComboBox.getEditor().getText().isEmpty();

                if (categoryComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
                    categoryComboBox.getEditor().setText(categoryComboBox.getItems().get(categoryComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()));
                }

                String temp = categoryComboBox.getEditor().getText();

                categoryComboBox.getItems().clear();
                categoryComboBox.getItems().addAll(categoryComboBoxItemsList);

                if (!emptyTextField) {
                    categoryComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(temp);
                } else {
                    categoryComboBox.getEditor().setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite old topic, but since I have just had this problem, I assembled my solution of parts that were already mentioned.
Like @RicherdK already said, you can use [controlsfx](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx) and the most simple way to bind it is like he said:

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textfield,"text to suggest", "another text to suggest");
```

In the comments of his post is mentioned that this is quite slow for an autocomplete. This is true since it takes 250ms without a keyboard stroke to show the suggestions. Therefore you can just set the delay to whatever you want:

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textfield,"text to suggest", "another text to suggest").setDelay(50);
```

Beside this small detail, I had a problem using this lib, I had to add:

```
--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED
```

to my VM options. Some other people had similar problems, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695304/autocompletionbinding-cannot-access-class-com-sun-javafx-event-eventhandlermanag) and make sure your JavaFx versions matches

Answer (score 0):

Trilogy's answer modification.

[image]

What's different?

On the constructor:

- `@param1 queryProcessor`: function that exposes the current text to
  allow the user to supply items (hardcoded: press CTRL+space to fire
  it)
- `@param2 toString`: function that converts objects retrieved from the
  query into strings to be internally matched with the text

When the contextMenu shows up, the first item will be focused by default, had to do some css inspection and `Platform.runlater` to ensure the first item was selected.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;

public class AutoCompleteTextField<S> extends TextField {

    ObjectProperty<S> selectedObject = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    final int maxEntries = 8;
    Function<S, String> toString;
    ContextMenu entriesPopup = new ContextMenu();
    Consumer<S> onSelected;
    boolean ignore = false;

    String textOccurenceStyle = "-fx-font-weight: bold; " + "-fx-fill: red;";
    Collection<S> entries;

    public AutoCompleteTextField() {

    }

    public AutoCompleteTextField(
        Function<String, Collection<S>> queryProcessor,
        Function<S, String> toString
    ) {

        setup(queryProcessor, toString);

    }

    public void setup(
        Function<String, Collection<S>> queryProcessor,
        Function<S, String> toString
    ) {

        this.toString = toString;
        this.entries = queryProcessor.apply("");

        textProperty().addListener((observableValue, s, text) -> {

            out("-TEXT-PROPERTY--");
            out("1 ignore "+ignore);
            
            if (ignore) {

                ignore = false;
                out("2 ignore "+ignore);
                out("end-TEXT-PROPERTY--");
                return;

            }

            processText(text);

        });

        focusedProperty().addListener((obs, old, focus) -> {

            out("-FOCUS-PROPERTY--");
            
            if (!focus) {

                entriesPopup.hide();
                ignore = true;
                out("1 ignore "+ignore);

                if (getSelectedObject() != null) {

                    setText(toString.apply(getSelectedObject()));
                    ignore = false;
                    out("2 ignore "+ignore);
                    out("end-FOCUS-PROPERTY--");

                }

            } else {

                processText(getText() == null ? "" : getText());

            }

        });

        selectedObjectProperty().addListener((obs, old, selected) -> {

            out("-SELECTED-OBJECT---");
            
            if (selected != null) {

                out("1 selected "+toString.apply(selected));
                ignore = true;
                out("2 ignore "+ignore);
                setText(toString.apply(selected));
                ignore = false;
                out("3 ignore "+ignore);

            } else {

                out("1 null selection");
                clear();
                out("2 ignore "+ignore);

            }
            out("end-SELECTED-OBJECT---");

        });

        entriesPopup.showingProperty().addListener((obs, old, showing) -> {

            out("-POPUP-SHOWING-PROPERTY---");
            
            if (showing) {

                out("1 entries size "+entriesPopup.getItems().size());
                if (entriesPopup.getItems().size() > 0) {

                    Platform.runLater(() -> {

                        var item = entriesPopup.getSkin().getNode().lookup(".menu-item");
                        out("2 item "+item);

                        if (!item.isFocused()) {

                            out("3 item is focused "+!item.isFocused());
                            item.requestFocus();
                            this.fireEvent(
                                new KeyEvent(
                                    KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, "", "", KeyCode.DOWN, false, false,
                                    false, false
                                )
                            );
                            out("4 focused next item");
                            out("end-POPUP-SHOWING-PROPERTY---");

                        }

                    });

                }

            }

        });

        entriesPopup.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {

            if (e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE)) { // allows the user to use
                                                                                                // whitespace

                out("-ENTRIES-POPUP-KEY-PRESSED---");
                out("consume space bar");
                e.consume();

            }

        });

        addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {

            if (e.isShortcutDown() && e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE)) {

                out("-KEY-CTRL-SPACE---");
                e.consume();
                out("1 hide popup");
                entriesPopup.hide();
                var text = getText();
                out("2 text "+text);
                this.entries = queryProcessor.apply(text);
                out("3 entries "+this.entries.size());
                out("4 caret pos "+getCaretPosition());
                out("5 move caret by "+text.length());
                positionCaret(text.length());
                out("5 caret pos "+getCaretPosition());
                processText(text);

            }

        });

        addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {

            if (isFocused() && !entriesPopup.isShowing()) {

                out("-CLICKED----");
                out("1 ignore "+ignore);
                e.consume();
//              entriesPopup.hide();
                var text = getText();
//              this.entries = queryProcessor.apply(text);
//              clear();
//              setText(text);
//              positionCaret(text.length());
                processText(text);

            }

        });

    }

    public ContextMenu getPopup() { return entriesPopup; }

    void processText(String text) {

        out("text " + text);

        var searchResult = new LinkedList<S>();
        var pattern = Pattern.compile(".*" + text + ".*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        int matches = 0;

        for (S entry : entries) {

            if (matches >= maxEntries) {

                break;

            }

            var str = toString.apply(entry);

            if (str == null) {

                continue;

            }

            var matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

            if (matcher.matches()) {

                searchResult.add(entry);
                matches++;

            }

        }

        out("size " + searchResult.size());

        if (!entries.isEmpty()) {

            populatePopup(searchResult, text);

            if (entriesPopup.getItems().size() > 0) {

                if (getScene() != null) {

                    if (isFocused()) {

                        entriesPopup.show(AutoCompleteTextField.this, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

                    }

                }

            } else {

                entriesPopup.hide();

            }

        } else {

            entriesPopup.hide();

        }

    }

    public void replaceText(String text) {

        ignore = true;
        setText(text);
        ignore = false;

    }

    public void show() {

        entriesPopup.show(AutoCompleteTextField.this, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

    }

    private void populatePopup(List<S> searchResult, String text) {

        entriesPopup.getItems().clear();
        int count = Math.min(searchResult.size(), maxEntries);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            final String result = toString.apply(searchResult.get(i));
            final S itemObject = searchResult.get(i);
            int occurence = result.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase());

            if (occurence < 0) {

                continue;

            }

            Text matched = new Text(
                result.substring(occurence, occurence + text.length())
            );
            matched.setStyle(textOccurenceStyle);

            TextFlow entryFlow = new TextFlow(
                new Text(result.substring(0, occurence)), matched,
                new Text(result.substring(occurence + text.length(), result.length()))
            );

            CustomMenuItem item = new CustomMenuItem(entryFlow, true);
            item.setOnAction((ActionEvent actionEvent) -> {

//              onSelected.accept(itemObject);
                setSelectedObject(itemObject);
                entriesPopup.hide();
                replaceText(toString.apply(itemObject));
                selectAll();

            });

            entriesPopup.getItems().add(item);

        }

        if (entriesPopup.getItems().size() > 0) {

            entriesPopup.hide();

        }

    }

    public final ObjectProperty<S> selectedObjectProperty() {

        return this.selectedObject;

    }

    public final S getSelectedObject() {

        return this.selectedObjectProperty().get();

    }

    public final void setSelectedObject(final S selectedObject) {

        this.selectedObjectProperty().set(selectedObject);

    }
    
    // for debugging
    int c = 0;
    
    private void out(Object vals) {
//      System.out.print(c+"    ");
//      System.out.println(vals);
//      c++;
    }

}
```

sample application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AppTest extends Application{

    static class Item {
        final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this .nameProperty()
                                    .get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty()
                    .set(name);
        }

    }

    public ListProperty<Item> getItems(String query) {

        var items = new SimpleListProperty<Item>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

        // simulate query for new matches
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var item = new Item();
//          item.setName(query + i); //new matches found
            item.setName("item hi" + i);// no new matches found
            items.add(item);
        }

        return items;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        VBox v = new VBox();

        var itemtextfield = new AutoCompleteTextField<>(
            this::getItems,
            Item::getName
        );
        itemTextField.selectedObjectProperty().addListener((obs,old,selected)->{/* do something with the selected item */});

        v   .getChildren()
            .add(itemtextfield);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(v));
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Autocomplete Table Cell

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.components.AutoCompleteTextField;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class AutocompleteTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    StackPane autocompletePane = new StackPane();
    final AutoCompleteTextField<T> autocompleteTextField;
    final Label label = new Label();
    final Function<T, String> toString;

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface AutocompleteTableCellConfigurator<S, T> {

        public void accept(
            TableCell<S, T> cell, Label label,
            AutoCompleteTextField<T> autocompleteTextField
        );

    }

    public AutocompleteTableCell(
        Function<String, Collection<T>> itemsRefresher,
        Function<T, String> toString,
        AutocompleteTableCellConfigurator<S, T> consumer
    ) {

        this.autocompleteTextField = new AutoCompleteTextField<>(
            itemsRefresher, toString
        );
        autocompleteTextField   .selectedObjectProperty()
                                                    .addListener((obs, old, selected) -> {

                                                        commitEdit(selected);
                                                        getTableColumn().getTableView().requestFocus();

                                                    });
        autocompleteTextField.focusedProperty().addListener((obd, old, focused) -> {

            if (!focused)
                updateValue();

        });
        autocompletePane.getChildren().addAll(autocompleteTextField, label);
        autocompletePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        label   .textProperty()
                    .bind(
                        Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                            () -> getItem() == null ? null : toString.apply(getItem()),
                            itemProperty()
                        )
                    );
        label.visibleProperty().bind(editingProperty().not());
        label.managedProperty().bind(editingProperty().not());
        this.autocompleteTextField.setOnAction(e -> updateValue());
        this.toString = toString;
        autocompleteTextField.visibleProperty().bind(editingProperty());
        autocompleteTextField.setPrefWidth(0);

        if (consumer != null) {

            consumer.accept(this, label, autocompleteTextField);

        }

    }

    void updateValue() {

        var text = autocompleteTextField.getText();

        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {

            commitEdit(null);

        } else {

            if (previousValue != autocompleteTextField.getSelectedObject()) {

                commitEdit(getItem());

            }

        }

        getTableColumn().getTableView().requestFocus();
        autocompleteTextField.setSelectedObject(null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        autocompleteTextField.clear();
        setText(null);

        setGraphic(autocompletePane);

        if (!autocompletePane.getChildren().contains(label)) {

            autocompletePane.getChildren().add(0, label);

        }

        autocompletePane.setPadding(new Insets(-5, -10, -5, 0));

    }

    T previousValue;

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {

        super.startEdit();
        previousValue = getItem();

        if (getItem() != null) {

            autocompleteTextField.replaceText(toString.apply(getItem()));
            autocompleteTextField.selectAll();

        }

        autocompleteTextField.requestFocus();
        autocompletePane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));

    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {

        super.cancelEdit();
        autocompleteTextField.clear();
        autocompletePane.setPadding(new Insets(-5, -10, -5, 0));

    }

}
```

to use TableCell do something like

```
tbcItem.setCellFactory(
    AutocompleteTableCell.forTableColumn(s -> itemService.itemsProperty(), Item::getName)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use any external libraries like controlsfx , here  is my solution:

1. Create a TextField for the user to enter text.
2. Create a ListView to display the suggestions.
3. Bind the text property of the TextField to a string property in your JavaFX controller class.
4. Create an event handler for the text property that updates the suggestions based on the current value of the text field.
5. Populate the ListView with the suggestions.
6. Handle user interaction with the ListView to select a suggestion, which would then be displayed in the TextField.

Here's an example of what the code could look like in your JavaFX controller class:

```
public class AutocompleteController {

    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> suggestionsList;

    private final ObservableList<String> suggestions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public void initialize() {
        text.bind(textField.textProperty());
        text.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> updateSuggestions(newValue));
        suggestionsList.setItems(suggestions);
        suggestionsList.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            String selectedSuggestion = suggestionsList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (selectedSuggestion != null) {
                textField.setText(selectedSuggestion);
                suggestions.clear();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateSuggestions(String enteredText) {
        // Clear the previous suggestions
        suggestions.clear();

        // Get the new suggestions based on enteredText and add them to the suggestions list
        List<String> newSuggestions = getSuggestions(enteredText);
        suggestions.addAll(newSuggestions);
    }

    private List<String> getSuggestions(String enteredText) {
        // Implement your logic to retrieve suggestions based on enteredText
        // ...

        return suggestions;
    }
}
```

If you want your suggestion listview to be dynamic so that its height depends on the items on the listview create a DoubleBinding that calculates the height of the ListView based on the number of items in the list and the fixed cell size. The binding is then applied to the prefHeight property of the ListView to make the height dynamic.

Here is an example:

```
suggestionsList.setFixedCellSize(24.0); // Set a fixed height for each cell

DoubleBinding heightBinding = new DoubleBinding() {
    {
        super.bind(suggestionsList.getItems());
    }
    @Override
    protected double computeValue() {
        return suggestionsList.getFixedCellSize() * suggestionsList.getItems().size();
    }
};

suggestionsList.prefHeightProperty().bind(heightBinding);
```