# javafx autocomplete event handler

Tags: javafx, autocomplete, textfield

I need your help as I am trying to make textfield that when you type character it drops down suggestions I tried to use controlsfx and put my function on key press handler but I got this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Comment: Extend the question with the code you have, otherwise it is impossible to tell what's wrong with it...

Comment: public class Controller {

    public TextField aa;

    public void init()
    {
        aa =new TextField();
    }
    public void drop(ActionEvent event)
    {
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(

                aa,

                "FIRST","SECOND");



    }
}

Comment: <GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
  <children>
     <VBox prefHeight="476.0" prefWidth="486.0">
        <children>
           <TextField fx:id="aa" onKeyPressed="#drop" />
           <ListView fx:id="a" prefHeight="118.0" prefWidth="486.0" />
        </children>
     </VBox>
  </children>
</GridPane>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX TextField Auto-suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861056/javafx-textfield-auto-suggestions)