# How to set position of a Node relative to another Node in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have two controls in my JavaFx Application
1. TextField
2. ListView

I want to place ListView just below the TextField using co-ordinates of TextField.
Because position of TextField changes.

Details :

I am creating auto suggestion text field for my project which requires to pop up a list when users type something in text field. that text field may exist anywhere in the scene it can be in another list view also. So what I need precisely is how to obtain co-ordinates of text field on screen so that I can place list view just below the text field.

Comment: Use a `VBox`, or other [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) that achieves what you need

Comment: @James_D Thank you for your reply... Please refer to edit (I have added some details of my current scenario).

Comment: Depending on your exact use case, this maybe is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36861056/3795043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple options here:

- I think you might be better of using a `ContextMenu`. When you show a `ContextMenu` you can define a view that it should be shown relative to and a side of the view to show it.
- Should a `ContextMenu` not fulfill your demands, the easiest idea that I have is that you replace your `TextField` with a `VBox` and input the `TextField` and the `ListView` in the `VBox`. That will make them be together and you can just position the `VBox` like you would position your `TextField`.
- Last if you want to lay it out yourself, the TextField contains Properties like `layoutX` and `layoutY` and `height` and `width`. Using those you can calculate where to position your ListView (e.g. Y position of ListView would be `textField.layoutY + textField.height`). To keep this position up to date I see two options:

  - To position the `TextField` you have probably overwritten the `layoutChildrens` method of some `Parent`, so you can probably put this code there.
  - If not, you can also register `ChangeListeners` on those Properties to get notified when they change and reposition your ListView accordingly.

Comment: `layoutX` and `layoutY` won't give you the screen coordinates of the text field, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I think ChangeListeners would work for me.. :D

Comment: @James_D true, but I didn't understand why he needs screen coordinates in the first place so I didn't put a solution with localToScreen converting.

Comment: He mentions a popup: `Popup.show(...)` needs screen coordinates.

Comment: He says he needs to pop up a list. I didn't infer that it means he is using the Popup class. Might be you are right. If he does he will need to take a look at your answer. Or you want me to extend mine to include what you have in yours?

Answer (score 0):

To get the location of a text field in the screen coordinates, you can do

```
Bounds boundsInScreen = textField.localToScreen(textField.getBoundsInLocal());
```

This returns a `Bounds` object, from which you can get the various coordinates, e.g.

```
Popup popup = ... ;
popup.setWidth(boundsInScreen.getWidth());
popup.show(textField, boundsInScreen.getMinX(), boundsInScreen.getMaxY());
```

Answer (score 0):

I Created this helper class that does just that.

```
public class PositionUtils {

    public static void position(Region movable, Region reference, Anchor movableAnchor, Anchor referenceAnchor, float xOffset, float yOffset) {
        double x = reference.localToScene(reference.getBoundsInLocal()).getMaxX();
        double y = reference.localToScene(reference.getBoundsInLocal()).getMaxY();

        Point referencePoint = referenceAnchor.referencePoint;
        Point movablePoint = movableAnchor.movablePoint;

        x -= (0.5 * movable.getWidth()) * movablePoint.x;
        y += (0.5 * movable.getHeight()) * movablePoint.y;

        x += (0.5 * reference.getWidth()) * referencePoint.x;
        y -= (0.5 * reference.getHeight()) * referencePoint.y;

        movable.setLayoutX(x + xOffset);
        movable.setLayoutY(y + yOffset);
    }

    public static void position(Pane movable, Pane reference, Anchor movableAnchor, Anchor referenceAnchor) {
        position(movable, reference, movableAnchor, referenceAnchor, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void position(Pane movable, Pane reference, Side side) {
        position(movable, reference, side, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void position(Pane movable, Pane reference, Side side, float xOffset, float yOffset) {
        Anchor movableAnchor = null;
        Anchor referenceAnchor = null;
        switch (side) {
            case TOP:
                movableAnchor = Anchor.BOTTOM_CENTER;
                referenceAnchor = Anchor.TOP_CENTER;
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                movableAnchor = Anchor.TOP_CENTER;
                referenceAnchor = Anchor.BOTTOM_CENTER;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                movableAnchor = Anchor.CENTER_LEFT;
                referenceAnchor = Anchor.CENTER_RIGHT;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                movableAnchor = Anchor.CENTER_RIGHT;
                referenceAnchor = Anchor.CENTER_LEFT;
                break;
        }
        position(movable, reference, movableAnchor, referenceAnchor, xOffset, yOffset);
    }

    public enum Anchor {
        TOP_LEFT(new Point(0, 0), new Point(-2, 2)),
        TOP_CENTER(new Point(1, 0), new Point(-1, 2)),
        TOP_RIGHT(new Point(2, 0), new Point(0, 2)),
        CENTER_LEFT(new Point(0, -1), new Point(-2, 1)),
        CENTER(new Point(1, -1), new Point(-1, 1)),
        CENTER_RIGHT(new Point(1, -2), new Point(0, 1)),
        BOTTOM_LEFT(new Point(0, -2), new Point(-2, 0)),
        BOTTOM_CENTER(new Point(1, -2), new Point(-1, 0)),
        BOTTOM_RIGHT(new Point(2, -2), new Point(0, 0));

        public Point referencePoint;
        public Point movablePoint;

        Anchor(Point movablePoint, Point referencePoint) {
            this.referencePoint = referencePoint;
            this.movablePoint = movablePoint;
        }
    }

    public enum Side {
        TOP,
        BOTTOM,
        RIGHT,
        LEFT
    }
}
```