# I want textField to seach the from saved string in javafx

Tags: java

I am new in programming so i can't use databases or anything...

Can You please Help me to do this by The data saved in string.i want `TextField` to show predictions like google it the data matches the data already given in `string`.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861056/javafx-textfield-auto-suggestions

Comment: All over the map sir. can You explain in some easy method?

Comment: There really is no "easy" method to achieve this. The best you could do is, as the other answer of that question suggests, is to use the ControlsFX library's version.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a quick solution. Use [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/)'s autocomplete `TextField` (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42714843/7015661)).

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textfield,"text to suggest", "another text to suggest");
```

Just download and add the controlsFX `jar` to your build path. Or you could use the maven dependency as in the answer I referenced.