# How to add Auto Suggestion in Text field Javafx?

Tags: javafx-8, textfield, autosuggest

I am making a signup page. I have added text field in it.
I want to add auto suggestion in text fields.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these:

- [Simple JavaFX TextBox with AutoComplete functionality](https://gist.github.com/floralvikings/10290131)
- [AutoFill Textbox on item selection with keys](https://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/07/04/autofill-textbox-with-filtermode-in-javafx-2-0-custom-control/).
- [controlsfx textfields AutoComplete](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/search?q=controlsfx+auto+complete&unscoped_q=controlsfx+auto+complete)
- ControlsFX's autocomplete TextField as follows:

> TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textfield,"text to suggest", "another
>   text to suggest");

Use maven dependency OR download and add the controlsFX jar to the build path.

- [JavaFX TextField Auto-suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36861056/10736243)

Comment: I am new to java. Is there any easy way? I cannot Understand it.

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: Thankyou very much bro for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. The right way to thank someone on stack overflow is to upvote and accept their answer.  Once you get 15 reputation you will be able to upvote.

Comment: Ok bro. I am new user. Now i understand it