# Javafx detect textfield change and determine caret position

Tags: javafx, textfield, changelistener

I'm implementing the AutoComplete logic in Javafx. A `TextField` is for user input and every time it got updated, the listener will be triggered. And then a dropdown menu which is a `listView` will display the matched results.

So the problem is that how can I get the updated caret position in `TextField` when the `textProperty` listener is in process?

I'm currently using `textfield.getCaretPosition()`, but it will only return the previous position.

Any inputs will be appreciated!

```java
        commandTextField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                                String oldText, String newText) {

                // Following line will return previous caret position
                commandTextField.getCaretPosition();

                ...//autocomplete logic omitted
            }
        });
```

**EDIT:**
The reason that I need to get the caret position is that I need to know the position where the input is changed and show suggestions correspondingly.

```java
            textField.caretPositionProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                caretPosition = newValue.intValue();
            });

            textField.textProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<String>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

                ...//autocomplete Logic
            }
```

In the above case, the `textProperty` listener will be invoked first and followed by `caretPositionProperty`, therefore there is no way to get updated caret position in my case.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue it will help others to understand what your issue is exactly

Comment: looks like the internal update of the textField is not yet complete - try to use a TextFormatter

Comment: Alternatively I have seen some previously implemented AutoComplete ComboBox's you could take a look into something like that as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX TextField Auto-suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861056/javafx-textfield-auto-suggestions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the intended use of the API, but you could use a `TextFormatter` constructed with an `UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>` as parameter. This is usually used to prevent/modify undesired changes to the text, but in this case we'll just use the `Change` object to get you the data you want.

The following example "suggests" possibilities each one replacing the selected section with some string:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();

    String[] replacements = { "foo", "bar", "42", "zap" };
    listView.getItems().setAll(replacements);

    TextField textField = new TextField();
    TextFormatter<?> formatter = new TextFormatter<>((UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>) change -> {
        int a = change.getAnchor();
        int b = change.getCaretPosition();
        String newText = change.getControlNewText();

        String prefix = newText.substring(0, Math.min(a, b));
        String suffix = newText.substring(Math.max(a, b));

        listView.getItems().clear();

        for (String mid : replacements) {
            listView.getItems().add(prefix + mid + suffix);
        }

        // do not change anything about the modification
        return change;
    });
    textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(listView, textField));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

There are plenty more properies available including the text and carret and anchor positions before the change, see [the javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! This approach perfectly solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add listener to caretPositionProperty.

```java
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class TextFieldCaretApp extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {            
            TextField textField = new TextField();
            Scene scene = new Scene(textField);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

            textField.caretPositionProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                System.out.println("caretPosition=" + newValue);
            });

            textField.textProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<String>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                System.out.println("text=" + newValue);
            });
        }
    }
```