# Showing Duplicate Menu Items in Context Menu with TextField. JavaFx. JDK 14

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, desktop-application, controlsfx

I want the program to show context menu when user starts typing.
The context menu should display all the String from array list which the user is typing (Like search). It should change as the user types or changes value in text field.
The problem is its working but it is giving me duplicate values. but when i try printing the sorted list, it doesnt contain duplicate values. I have attach pictures below.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZCzV.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjA2E.png)

FIXED THE ISSUE

by removing the items from Context Menu with
CM.getItems().clear();

Rather than removing it with loop.
Somehow this was causing the issue
CM.getItems().remove(i);

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXAutoCompletePopup;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class controller implements Initializable{
    @FXML TextField TF;
    @FXML ContextMenu CM = new ContextMenu();
    
    public void listener() {
        
        TF.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                
                
                for(int i=0;i<CM.getItems().size();i++) {
                    CM.getItems().remove(i);
                }
                TF.setContextMenu(CM);
                if (!newValue.isBlank()) {
                    CM.show(TF, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                    ArrayList<String> sortList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
                        String item = list.get(i);
                        //if(item.toLowerCase().regionMatches(true, 0, newValue.toLowerCase(), 0, newValue.length())) {
                        if(item.toLowerCase().startsWith(newValue.toLowerCase())) {
                            sortList.add(item);
                        } 
                    }
                    System.out.println(sortList);
                    for(int i=0;i<sortList.size();i++) {
                        //MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(sortList.get(i));
                        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(sortList.get(i));
                        CM.getItems().add(menuItem);
                        System.out.println(sortList.get(i) + ", " + CM.getItems().get(i).toString());
                    }
                    CM.show(TF, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                } else if(newValue.isBlank()) {
                    CM.hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ArrayList<String> list;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listener();
        
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("aaa");
        list.add("bat");
        list.add("bating");
        list.add("det");
        list.add("elf");
        list.add("foo");
        list.add("git");
        list.add("horse");

        
        CM.setOnAction(e -> {
            TF.setText(((MenuItem)e.getTarget()).getText());
            TF.positionCaret(((MenuItem)e.getTarget()).getText().length());
        });
        
        
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.controller">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="-28.0" layoutY="43.0" prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="TF" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Have you tried some type of `Set`?

Comment: I am sorry, I am bit new to programming. What do you mean by set?

Comment: A Set is a collection that has not duplicate items. You declare one like this ```Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();```

Comment: java naming conventions, please

Comment: _I am sorry, I am bit new to programming_ then start learning by working through a tutorial on java/data structures. You _must_ know the basics, no way around (otherwise you wont understand the comments/answers, as you just noticed :)

Comment: @kleopatra Yes, I am doing it everyday. Thank you.

Comment: Got the fix guys, 

//Rather than this
//---------------
for(int i=0;i<CM.getItems().size();i++) {
                    CM.getItems().remove(i);
 }
//----------------------------------------
// just, used this, without the loop
//-----------------------
CM.getItems().clear();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX TextField Auto-suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861056/javafx-textfield-auto-suggestions)

Comment: @Sedrick Thanks sedrick. I tried the one you sent before, but didn't work for me. But I fixed my code and its now working.